# preventDefault() on keyup event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

I cannot get `preventDefault()` to work.

Here are some different code variations I have tried:

First:

```
$(document).keyup(function (evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 192) {
        alert('192');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Second:

```
$(document).keyup(function (evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 192) {
        alert('192');
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Third:

```
$(document).keyup(function (evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 192) {
        alert('192');
        evt.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Only alert works.
Everything works on Opera,but not on Chrome and IE
Also tried `keydown` and `keypress`.
On `keypress` script doesn't work.
`$('#thetext').keydown(function(evt){});` neither works this. 
Here is whole code: http://bbullett.tk/test/kakey.html

```
Key 192 = `
```

I'm trying to insert some text or symbol instead of `

Comment: Please indent your code so that it is readable. Thank you! Which key is `192`? What is the default behaviour when this key is pressed?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What would stopping the keyup event accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to insert some symbol instead of `

Comment: you need to capture the `keydown` event.. character would've already been written when `keyup` is triggered

Answer (score 52):

Listening to `keyup` event is too late for calling `preventDefault`, try listening to `keypress` or `keydown` instead.

```
$('input[type=text], textarea').on('keydown', function(event){
    if (event.which == 192) {
        console.log('192');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Note that jQuery normalizes `which` property and it's cross-browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/763ys/

Comment: Check manually for `event.e.isDefaultPrevented()` and process. It will be more simple on many cases.

Comment: `keydown` is the solution for me.

Answer (score 8):

There is no default behaviour for `.keyup()`; it fires after the key press which triggers the default behaviour. Use `.keydown() or`.keypress()` instead.

**source:** http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

Answer (score 2):

You are using JQuery, which normalises the differences between browsers, so you only need to to check the evt.which property. See the JQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

As others have said - keyup is too late to stop the processing of the key. Use keydown or keypress instead. http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

Comment: Any idea how to use keydown on an Android browser though? Keydown and keypress aren't very useful if they don't work on all platforms...

Answer (score 0):

see working example here http://jsfiddle.net/WGSvm/

In all three examples you have used

```
$(document).keyup(function (evt) {  });
```

I would say use particular div id instead of `$(document).keyup(function (evt) { });`

like `$("#DivIdName").keyup(function (evt) {   });` 
and also use `onkeypress` 
strictly, because if you use `onkeyup` 
it has already executed its default task of printing or whatever it is.