# jquery from submit not handled correctly, event.preventDefault() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the form with the folowing HTML (in modal window using bootbox.js)

```
<div class="bootbox-body">
    <form id="change_phrase" style="">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phrase_fld">Фраза</label>
            <input type="text" name="dialog_field" class="form-control" id="phrase_fld" placeholder="Enter phrase">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I need to handle `enter` key press while in `input` field with the following code:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#phrase_fld', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e);     
    if(e.keyCode == 13){                    
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('button.btn-success').trigger('click');
     }
 });
```

But when I press `enter` while in `#phrase_fld` input field I get my html page reloaded and `?dialog_field=some+new+phrase` query string appended to my url in browser. Maybe `e.preventDefault()` is not working? In my console I see `isDefaultPrevented: f`. Any ideas how to fix that would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Related: [preventDefault() on keyup event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055096/preventdefault-on-keyup-event-not-working)

Comment: Note that you can use the [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method instead of several `parent` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form submission is not trigged as the default behaviour for the `keyup` event. It is too late for that.

You need to capture it during either the `keydown` or `keypress` event.

Comment: yes, but why `keyup` event is not working properly? If I use `keypress` or `keydown` and `preventDefault()` for them, I dont see my text entered into input field. Though `enter` click is handled properly

Comment: @Masha — Because it is too late. It runs **after** the effect of the key press has occurred. If you press A it types A, if you press Enter, it submits the form. If you prevent pressing A, then it doesn't type A. If you prevent pressing Enter, it doesn't submit the form. Keyup doesn't have a default behaviour, so there is nothing to prevent.

Comment: @Masha It works as it's supposed to work. Browser waits and executes your event handler before submitting the form.

Answer (score -1):

Try This Code:

```
$('body').delegate('#phrase_fld', 'keypress', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(e);
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('button.btn-success').trigger('click');
        }     
});
```

Comment: `delegate` is deprecated

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer.